# How Active Right to Left ScrollBar in DotNetBar DataGridView (Win Form) - C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, right-to-left, dotnetbar

I Work With C# in Win Form.

I use DotNetBar's DataGridView (DataGridViewX) And Change RightToLeft Mode To Yes.

But Horizontal Scroll Bar for DataGridViewX Started from Left Side While Must Start from Right Side.

Look at Under Picture to Get My Problem:

[image]

How Solve Problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`DataGridViewX.CurrentCell = DataGridViewX[0, DataGridViewX.Rows.Count - 1];`